# ./ucgenAlanı.java:23: error: missing return statement }

Tags: java

I am trying to get at an area of triangle.
But i have an error that  ./ucgenAlanı.java:23: error: missing return statement         }
Can you help me ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ucgenAlanı {

    private double a1,a2,a3;

    public void setDimensions( double newa1,double newa2,double newa3 ) {
        a1 = newa1;
        a2 = newa2;
        a3 = newa3;
    }

    public double readInput() {
        Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" kenarları giriniz : ");
        a1=klavye.nextDouble();
        a2=klavye.nextDouble();
        a3=klavye.nextDouble();
    }

    public double getArea() {
        double s= (a1 + a2 + a3) / 2;
        double area = Math.sqrt( s*(s-a1)*(s-a2)*(s-a3) );
        System.out.println( area + "ucgenin alanı" );   
        return area;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readInput` method doesn't return a `double` value .

Looking at your code change the method return type to `void` to fix the problem